change IFC export settings in Model Derivative API
we have an integration for using the Model Derivative API to convert models to IFC format. The documentation specifies that it's possible to use custom conversion settings, but there’s a small gap I would like to understand. When we tried to use the endpoint with the "Export setting" parameter and specified the setting name, the process didn’t work. However, when we tried specifying the version name, the process worked and converted the correct version.
UI in Revit
IFC4 Reference View [BuildingService] VS IFC4 Reference View
The question is, we are trying to perform a conversion that includes the project parameters of the project and not just the default Revit parameters. The option to select is "Export Revit property sets."
How can we perform a conversion (preferably to IFC4) that includes all the parameters in the model?
I tried to use conversion settings name but it didn't work.

Here are the supported built-in IFC export setups in Model Derivative that you can specify in the exportSettingName when submitting the translation request.

IFC2x3 Coordination View 2.0
IFC2x3 Coordination View
IFC2x3 GSA Concept Design BIM 2010
IFC2x3 Basic FM Handover View
IFC2x2 Coordination View
IFC2x2 Singapore BCA e-Plan Check
IFC2x3 Extended FM Handover View
IFC4 Reference View
IFC4 Design Transfer View

However, there is a known limitation that Model Derivative API doesn't support the custom IFC export settings set created by the recent Revit IFC Addin, which IFC exporter version is newer than v22.1.1.0. (Wishlist item: RVTLMV-3166)
Our apologies for the inconveninece!
ref: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/export-ifc-rvt-using-model-derivative-api
